# Exercise chapter 5 Stein complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that for every z the product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}cos(\frac{z}{2^k}) = \frac{sin(z)}{z}$
[Hint: Use the fact that $sin(2z) = 2*sin(z)*cos(z)$.]

Then my idea was the following, I have that:
$P_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}cos(\frac{z}{2^k}) = cos(\frac{z}{2}) * cos(\frac{z}{4}) *cos(\frac{z}{8}) *...*cos(\frac{z}{2^n})$

When I use the hint for each one of the cosine terms I have that any terms vanishing then finally

$P_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}cos(\frac{z}{2^k}) = \frac{sin(z)}{2^n*sin(\frac{z}{2^n})}$

But I can take the $lim_{n→\infty}$ to see if $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}cos(\frac{z}{2^k}) = \frac{sin(z)}{z}$

Does anyone have an idea, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $\frac {\sin (\frac z {2^{n}})}  {(\frac z {2^{n}})} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Then $z*P_n = \frac{sin(z)*z}{2^n * sin(z/2^n)}$ is that what you say?

Comment: Yes, and so $zP_n=\frac {\sin\, z} {f_n(z)}$ where $f_n(z)=\frac {\sin (z/2^{n})} {z/2^{n}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.